What is the resulting initiative order when a readied action triggers after a summoned monsters action but before the summoner?
In a recent game we had a situation where the PC summoned some monsters.
Per SRD Summon monster 1:

It appears where you designate and acts immediately, on your turn. It attacks your opponents to the best of its ability.

On later turns, it made sense for the summoned creatures to go before the wizard so the wizard could react to the results of the monsters actions. Some rounds later, the summons acted and then the wizard attempted to cast a spell. The BBG attempted to counterspell.
SRC Special actions: ready action

If you take your readied action in the next round, before your regular turn comes up, your initiative count rises to that new point in the order of battle, and you do not get your regular action that round.

Because the BBG used their ready action, their inititive rises to that new point.
On the following turn is the innitive order:
summons  -> BBG -> Wizard => Because the summons had already acted
Order by Dex, rerolling ties => because the inititive for the BBG is set to the same number as the summons and wizard
BBG -> summons -> Wizard => Because the summons and wizard go at the same time and the BBG goes just before that
BBG -> Wizard -> summons => because the wizard acted before the summons by virtue of summoning them. (never mind they could have shifted in the following rounds)
Or something else entirely?
(If it matters, the summons were called using a standard action rather then a full round action.)

Hi Corbin, it looks like you've accidentally made two accounts. You should go through the process of getting them merged.

The summon and the summoner share a turn, namely the summoner’s turn. The summon never rolls initiative and its Dexterity modifier is never relevant to tie-breaking.
Because it’s a single, shared turn, it doesn’t matter which order you resolve the actions, and it doesn’t even have to remain consistent. You can even interleave the actions: you could have the summoner move, then the summon attack, and then the summoner could cast a spell.
If another character’s readied action is triggered during this shared turn (regardless of who is acting at the time), the character with the readied action has their initiative set to the same as that of the turn. This is a separate turn with the same initiative, so now we do need to figure out the tie—but again have a special rule for it. In this case, the rules for readied actions say that the readier’s next turn happens just before the turn of the triggerer’s next turn, so that’s what happens: regardless of who triggered the readied action, both summon and summoner use the same turn, so the person who readied the action goes before that shared turn.
Since it came up in comments: the summon continues to use the summoner’s turn—until something changes that. That is, by default, creatures’ turns don’t change automatically, so when the summon takes its first turn during the summoner’s turn in which it appears, that sets it up to share the summoner’s turn in the next round, and the next round, and so on. However, while nothing changes that by default, it can change—for example, the summon can delay or ready, and change its turn from the summoner’s turn to the turn right before wherever it delayed to or whoever triggered its readied action.

Does this mean that summons cannot use the ready action?

@CorbinMatheson That is an extremely good question, and I don’t think it’s actually answered anywhere. I guess, strictly speaking, so far as I know, nothing says they can’t, but equally nothing says what actually happens if they do: either the ready rules “win” and the summon starts acting on its own turn (based on its new initiative), or the summon rules “win” and the ready action doesn’t work (or, in the most broken reading, ready works but can’t change the summon’s initiative, so it can ready without changing its initiative—this is a bad idea but supportable based on the text).

So, my interpertation was that the summon rules set the summons starting inititive (instead of rolling for initive ) but that after that it functioned acording to inititive rules as normal as they were self willed creatures.

Always played it ^that^ way.

@CorbinMatheson It says that the summon acts on the summoner’s turn, not that it acts at the same initiative as the summoner.

"It appears where you designate and acts immediately, on your turn."
This can be either instantanious rule, IE when you cast the spell it blinks into existance and acts at the same time you do. OR it can be a contineous rule but that would indicate it keeps appearing and acting every round.
It continues to say: "It attacks your opponents to the best of its ability." Summons are not extensions of you and "If you can communicate with the creature, you can direct it not to attack, to attack particular enemies, or to perform other actions." Of which ready and delay are explict actions.

@CorbinMatheson Sure, I’ll buy that it acts on your turn until something changes that—which nothing does by default, but would if the summon used delay or ready. That does seem to resolve the ambiguity, though I would caution that this is almost-certainly not an intended interaction, but rather just a serendipitous coincidence.
